# Pytorch list of supported GPU hardware for each release (Ubuntu18.04)

Tags: pytorch, nvidia, ubuntu-18.04, torchvision

I have an old GPU and pytorch says it is too old to support:

```
    Found GPU0 GeForce GTX 670 which is of cuda capability 3.0.
    PyTorch no longer supports this GPU because it is too old.
    The minimum cuda capability that we support is 3.5.
```

First question is what is this 3.0 / 3.5 referring to ? Clearly not cuda, nvidia driver nor pytorch? 
Secondly, I know I can build Pytorch from source in order to have more support, however it's unclear what hardware pytorch supports when built from source, or even when installed with pip. I'm at the point where the likely pytorch version I need, requires python2, and cuda 9, so I'm spending solid time changing a bunch of software versions without knowing whether any of it will work.

Also if I were to get a newer GPU, I don't know whether it is currently supported.

Any way to have a list of supported NVIDIA hardware of pytorch? Ideally for each releases, but at least for current release?

I run an Nvidia GTX670 with Nvidia Driver 430.50. I changed from cuda 10 to 9, but seeing I might have to build pytorch 0.3.1, I think cuda8 is needed since when runnin `python setup.py install` in v0.3.1 i get:

```
CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:560: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCHalf.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/THC.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/THC.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: google "cuda compute capability" and all will be revealed

Comment: hehe thanks, and any idea about the torch&cuda version <-> minimum Compute Capability, outside of current torch v1.4.0 requires >3.5